# SELECT DISTINCT OVER TEXT as needs over common query in PostgreSQL and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, distinct, clob

My table

Name - Folder
Column - description of text data type

```
SELECT DISTICT description 
from FOLDER
```

works fine in PostgreSQL, but fails in oracle with the error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

I need a common query that works in both PostgreSQL and Oracle for this
`SELECT DISTINCT description from FOLDER`.

Comment: You can't use CLOB in Oracle then, use `varchar`

Comment: But why would you need a DISTINCT over a column named `description`?

Comment: Is there any common way (code) to convert CLOB to varchar both in PostgreSQL and Oracle

Comment: Needed DISTINCT over description is a functional requirement

Comment: In Postgres it's as easy as `alter table folder alter description type varchar`. In Oracle you need to create a new (`varchar`) column, copy the content of the old column to the new one, drop the old one and rename the new one back to `description`

Comment: Sorry, we can't change the database schema, just want a wrapper that's common in both postgres and oracle to display the distinct values. Do we have any function in both oracle and postgres to convert CLOB to string

Comment: @bngk, what is the maximum length of your `CLOB` column? If it is less than `4000` you can use `to_char()`

Comment: Yes, In oracle to_char(description) works fine, but postgres expects a second argument. so couldn't write a common to_char(description) in both postgres and oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `DISTINCT` with `CLOB` column. You can use `TO_CHAR` (when the maximum length of CLOB column is less than `4000`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT to_char(description) from FOLDER;
```

Since you mentioned in comment that it is working fine for oracle, I assume there is no length issues. As you are looking for common solution for both `POSTGRES` and `ORACLE`, I would propose `CAST`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(description as varchar(3000)) from FOLDER;
```

This should work in both databases.Change the `VARCHAR(N)` accordingly upto the maximum limit.

CAUTION : I won't recommend using `VARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR2` in oracle.

> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings.